# Reduce 100% div width by certain amount of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below code which I need to keep original css as is. Problem is the inner div has a border value of 10px which makes the inner div 20px wider than the outer div. Can I adjust the width of the inner div by minus 20px to fix. I have tried negative margins etc but no luck any ideas?

```
<style>

.content {  
width: 90%; 
float: left;

}

.content-inner {    
float: left;
width: 100%; 
background: #6DA249;
border: 10px solid #333333;

}
body {

padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;


}

</style>

<div class="content">
<div class="content-inner">

dfg

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `<div>` has a width of 100%, and contained by its parent, by default; if you remove that property, it should work automatically. Though why is it set a 100% width *and* floated? You may need to provide a little more context.

Comment: Also, there's always the good friend `calc`: `width: calc((100%) - 20px);`

Comment: Calc is not supported in older browsers (IE < 9), so use only if you don't need support for older browsers

Comment: dont float your divs.. unless you're try to be IE7 compatible.. `display:inline-block;`.. ontop of that.. why are you doing float with `100%`? just `display:block;`.. Since you're using `float`.. where is `clear`?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution, that avoids rewriting properties on the parent `<div>` would be to add a single, further, rule to your CSS for the inner-`<div>`:

```
.content-inner {
  /* other CSS */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This causes the browser to include the borders (and padding) in the assigned width of the elements of that class.

Failing that, of course, you could use the CSS `calc()` function:

```
.content-inner {
  /* other CSS */
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

I do feel it worth reiterating, though, that by default a `<div>`, set to `display: block;` will take the full-width of its parent element and its borders contained within. This question *feels* like you're trying to solve a problem that exists because of a deliberate (though unexplained) choice.

Simply put: if you *don't* float the `<div>`, and leave, or set, its `display` as `block`, then you won't need to use the somewhat experimental (as defined by MDN, in the references below) CSS and will have CSS that's functional back to the days of IE 6 (if not earlier).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)<sup>[specifications](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#box-sizing), [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)</sup>.
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)<sup>[specifications](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#calc-notation), [compatibility](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#calc-notation)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce a div by pixels if its set via percent.  As you stated you can **position** things that way, example set a div with 30% width to a negative margin.  margin:-20px;  etc.  but you cannot **resize them.**  The solution is to simply drop the percent of the width by a percentage point or two.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do this - trying to make pixel- and percent-based values correspond to each other in css is headache-y; just think about this: as soon as the page size changes, the percentage-based element will change size, but the pixel-based element will not.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of a border is to extend the overall dimensions of its element.

You can change this default behavior with the following rule:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

That css is pretty much intended to resolve exactly this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers are more interesting, but as an alternative.

consider these three Css Declarations.
`width: auto;` `margin: 0;` `display:block;`

the auto `width` of the element should fill it's parent container, when the margin is set to `0` on `margin-left` and `margin-right`, the `display` is set to `block`.

I removed float and the percentage widths..

---

### Sample Code Snippet

```css
 .content {  
   /*
      width: 90%; 
      float: left;
   */
      position:relative;
      left:0; top:0;
   
      display:block;
      margin:0; padding:0;
      width: auto;
      /*margin is 0, so with width set to auto, and display being block.. width auto should go to 100%*/  

    }

    .content-inner {    
    /*
      float: left;
      width: 100%; 
    */
      
      position:relative;
      left:0;top:0;
      
      background: #6DA249;
      border: 10px solid #333333;
      
      display:block; 
      width:auto;
      margin:0; padding:0;    
      
      overflow:auto;
    }

    body {
      position:relative;
      left:0;top:0;
      
      display: block;
      padding: 0; margin: 0;
      width:auto;
      
      overflow:auto;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inner">

    dfg

    </div>
    </div>
```

---

when you set `float` on an element, and **don't** specify `clear` on the parent element (Container), the properties (width and height) of the parent don't pickup and/or account for the size of the floated child element.. which will mess up the auto `width`.

Additionally, you will want to explicitly set the `overflow` style declaration on the parent/containers..